# Database Migration Approach

Tags: sql-server, database, database-migration

I have a few databases that I want to migrate to another server. These are production Databases, what is the best way to Migrate

1) Take full back up of the Current Databse and then Restore it on to the other Server.

or

2) Detach and then Copy the mdf/ldf files on the Destination Server and then attach the files there.

I know that after Migrating Sql Logins and Sql Agent Jobs will have to be created manually. Are there any other risks that come to mind?

Any help will be helpful.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77376/migrate-all-databases-from-one-sql-server-2005-to-another

Answer (score 0):

For Login transfer use "sp_help_revlogin" you get the script 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992 
this Stored procedure list out all the instance login not particular database login. One special thing about this stored procedure is no need to do orphaned fix. Just migrate the logins and check. It works.